# In Matthew 10:25, who is Beelzebub/Beelzeboul?

Tags: greek, matthew, grammar, onomastics, grammatical-historical

> [Mat 10:25 NASB] (25) "It is enough for the disciple that he become like his teacher, and the slave like his master. If they have called the head of the house Beelzebul, how much more [will they malign] the members of his household!

And is it "Lord of the flies" or "Lord of the demons"?

Comment: בַ֤עַל means *lord* and זְבוּב֙ means *fly*.

Comment: But what does the Greek mean, in this context? And, of course, as usual, there are variants involved! And etymology misleads as often as it tells us anything.

Comment: It is a Philistine proper name of one of their idols.

Comment: One linguistic wrinkle regarding that assertion is that it lacks the definite article. In Greek, the definite article before that name indicates that it is a name. Odd, huh?

Comment: Βεελζεβοὺλ ἄρχοντι τῶν δαιμονίων.
(in Matt 12:24, NA28)

Comment: Is this actually reference to the Phoenician Baal>  זְבֻל ... n.[m.] elevation, height, lofty abode

Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 259). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

Comment: Gesenius and every other source I've seen do not show that usage: https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H1167&t=NIV

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Variants are such a pain!

Comment: But in Hebrew zebub means fly and zeboul means lofty abode. – Perry Webb 47 mins ago

Comment: With a little imagination, I suppose it could be construed as the background for Paul's *[Eph 2:2 NASB] (2) in which you formerly walked according to the course of this world, according to the prince of the power of the air, of the spirit that is now working in the sons of disobedience.* I have a different understanding of that, but I figured I mention it.

Comment: As of this writing I've received two very good answers, from Dottard and @TonyChan, each having received 2 upvotes. I guess I'll wait for another voter to break the tie. Related: A couple of posts of mine on Quora, neither of which quite satisfy me: quora.com/Is-Beelzebub-the-same-as-the-devil/answer/… – Ruminator 3 mins ago

Comment: @ Ruminator - William Golding wrote a novel (**Lord of the Flies**) based on this terminology, highlighting the "Fallen Nature of Man." Even *innocent* boy scouts succombed to demonic conduct all on their own!  The Jewish antagonists of Jesus seemed to recognize this connection between human nature and evil propensities inspired by the spirit realm.

Answer (score 3):

The Hebrew term appears in the OT in
2 Kings 1:2

> Now Ahaziah had fallen through the lattice of his upper room in Samaria and injured himself. So he sent messengers, saying to them, "Go and consult **Baal-Zebub**, the god of Ekron, to see if I will recover from this injury."

Strong's Concordance

> **Baal Zebub**: "Baal of flies," a Philistine god

This is the Lord of the flies.

In the NT Greek, it is Βεελζεβούλ

Strong's Concordance

> Beelzeboul: **Beelzebul**, a name of Satan
> Original Word: Βεελζεβούλ, ὁ
> Part of Speech: Proper Noun, Indeclinable

HELPS Word-studies

> 954 Beelzeboúl (translaterated from OT 1176/BaʽalZebūb, "the lord of flies" or "fly-god," cf. 2 Ki 1:2) – Beelzebul, a title of Satan which stresses he is the **prince over demons** ("demonic flies").

In Hebrew, it is "Lord of the flies". In Greek, it is "Lord of the demons". Both means Lord of evil creatures.

Comment: Hi Tony. Strong's and HELPS are not particularly authoritative. Can you please cite a lexicon or encyclopedia or something instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to BDAG,

> Βεελζεβούλ was originally a Philistine deity; the name means *Baal*
> (lord) *of flies* (2 Kings 1:2, 6) ... in the NT Beelzeboul is prince
> of hostile spirits ἄρχοντι τῶν δαιμονίων Matt 12:24, Luke 11:15, etc.

See also the appendix below for a very similar lexical entry.

The word occurs just seven times in the NT and can be classified as follows:

- Jesus uses the name Beelzeboul metaphorically to signify the Jewish leaders were followers of the devil, Matt 10:25, (Matt 12:27)
- Jesus is accused of being in league with the Beelzeboul, the prince of demons, Matt 12:24, 27, Mark 3:22, Luke 11:15, 18, 19
- Beelzeboul is called the leader/prince of the demons, Matt 12:24, Mark 3:22, 23, 26 (Beelzeboul = Satan here)

Thus, in the NT, "Beelzeboul" appears to have been used as another name for Satan, the prince of the demons.

**APPENDIX Thayers entry for Βηλζεβουλ**

Βηλζεβουλ and, as written by some (yet no Greek) authorities, Βηλζεβουβ (cod. B Βηζεβουλ, so manuscript א except in Mark 3:22; adopted by WH, see their Appendix, p. 159; cf. Buttmann, 6), ὁ, indeclinable, Beelzebul or Beelzebub, a name of Satan, the prince of evil spirits: Matthew 10:25; Matthew 12:24, 27; Mark 3:22; Luke 11:15, 18, 19. The form Βηλζεβουλ is composed of זְבוּל (rabbinical Hebrew for זֶבֶל dung) and בַּעַל, lord of dung or of filth, i. e. of idolatry; cf. Lightfoot on Matthew 12:21. The few who follow Jerome in preferring the form Βηλζεβουβ derive the name from זְבוּב בַּעַל, lord of flies, a false god of the Ekronites (2 Kings 1:2) having the power to drive away troublesome flies, and think the Jews transferred the name to Satan in contempt. Cf. Winers RWB under the word Beelzebub: and J. G. M(üller) in Herzog vol. i., p. 768ff; (BB. DD.; cf. also Meyer and Dr. James Morison on Matthew 10:25; some, as Weiss (on Mark, the passage cited; Biblical Theol. § 23 a.), doubt alike whether the true derivation of the name has yet been hit upon, and whether it denotes Satan or only some subordinate 'Prince of demons'). (Besides only in ecclesiastical writings, as Ev. Nicod. c. 1f.)

Comment: @Ruminator - that is not very different from the Greek